# Printing to command line midway through Selenium script - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
first_run = res_loop(url, tr)

if first_run > 0:
    xml_input = first_run
else:
    loop_decision = input("Do you want to run the script until a time slot is found?\n")
    if loop_decision[0].upper() == 'Y':
        loop_output = 0
        loop_ct = 1
        while loop_output == 0 and res_date_obj > datetime.now().date() and loop_ct <= 5:
            print(loop_ct)
            time.sleep(5)
            # time.sleep(60)
            loop_output = res_loop(url, tr)
            loop_ct += 1
            if loop_ct % 2 == 0:
                print(f"We've ran this script {loop_ct} times and haven't found anything, but we're still trying!")
        
        if loop_output > 0:
            xml_input = loop_output
        else:
            print("Sorry, no time slots became available.")

driver.quit()
```

In the code snippet above, the res_loop function uses the Selenium webdriver to interact with a site. The function loops multiple times, and I'd like it to be able to print to the command line to tell the user how many times the script has been run midway through the loop. If I set an input variable like loop_decision, the script will pause and print to the command line as desired, but otherwise, all of the print() commands will not appear on the command line until after the entirety of the script runs and the driver quits. Is there a way to "pause" Selenium so that it can print to the command line midway through execution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can pass `loop_ct` as an argument of `res_loop` and print inside it?

Edit 1:

I can't reproduce your problem. I used the code below:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


def res_loop(url, tr):
    # Do something with url and tr
    # ...

    # Simulates "Haven't found anything"
    return 0


url = 'my_url'
tr = 'my_tr'

first_run = res_loop(url, tr)

if first_run > 0:
    xml_input = first_run
else:
    loop_decision = input("Do you want to run the script until a time slot is found?\n")
    if loop_decision[0].upper() == 'Y':
        loop_output = 0
        loop_ct = 1
        while loop_output == 0 and loop_ct <= 5:
            print(loop_ct)
            time.sleep(5)
            loop_output = res_loop(url, tr)
            loop_ct += 1
            if loop_ct % 2 == 0:
                print(f"We've ran this script {loop_ct} times and haven't found anything, but we're still trying!")

        if loop_output > 0:
            xml_input = loop_output
        else:
            print("Sorry, no time slots became available.")

driver.quit()

print('Driver quit')
```

The code above printed correctly to the command line midway through execution.

```
Do you want to run the script until a time slot is found?
y
1
We've ran this script 2 times and haven't found anything, but we're still trying!
2
3
We've ran this script 4 times and haven't found anything, but we're still trying!
4
5
We've ran this script 6 times and haven't found anything, but we're still trying!
Sorry, no time slots became available.
Driver quit
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but I have print commands within the loop as well that also don't run until after the driver quits.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Edited.